# Best way for consuming RSS feeds

Tags: rss

What is the best way for consuming rss feeds ,which aren't pubsubhubbub enabled?
I thought with a php script ,which parses the feeds and it's called every 10 minutes.But when I have 100 feeds it will be slow process.
What do you recommend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a pool of threads that works to process the set of feeds that you get each time to distribute the work.